# How to get the inner tags from an XML file?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I'm sitting there for quite a while now, trying to process my xml file (similar to the one below). I want to check all  tags, if  is equal to a variable, and if so, then running readEntry() on the  tag.
I followed this example: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

I also found this Article([Difficulty with XML nested tags with XMLPullParser in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341391/difficulty-with-xml-nested-tags-with-xmlpullparser-in-android),which) deals with this topic.
I have already tried a few things but get either nothing or XmlPullParserException.

A Example of my XML:

```
<VpMobil>
     <Kopf>
         ...
     </Kopf>
     <FreieTage>
         ...
     </FreieTage>
     <Klassen>
          <Kl>
               <Kurz>5</Kurz>
               <Pl>
                    <Std>
                         <St>1</St>
                         <Fa>Fa1</Fa>
                         <Le>NAME</Le>
                         <Ra>1009</Ra>
                         <Nr>131</Nr>
                         <If/>
                    </Std>
                    <Std>
                         <St>2</St>
                         <Fa>Fa2</Fa>
                         <Le>NAME</Le>
                         <Ra>1004</Ra>
                         <Nr>132</Nr>
                         <If/>
                    </Std>
                </Pl>
           </Kl>
           <Kl>
               <Kurz>6</Kurz>
               <Pl>
                    <Std>
                         <St>1</St>
                         <Fa>Fa2</Fa>
                         <Le>NAME</Le>
                         <Ra>1046</Ra>
                         <Nr>131</Nr>
                         <If/>
                    </Std>
                    <Std>
                         <St>2</St>
                         <Fa>Fa3</Fa>
                         <Le>NAME</Le>
                         <Ra>1012</Ra>
                         <Nr>132</Nr>
                         <If/>
                    </Std>
                </Pl>
           </Kl>
      </Klassen>
 </VpMobil>
```

I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me how I can achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more unsuccessful attempts, I got the idea to convert the XML into a JSON ([Convert XML to JSON object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337394/convert-xml-to-json-object-in-android)) and continue working with it. That worked then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jackson library](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat%7Cjackson-dataformat-xml%7C2.8.11%7Cbundle) to parse XML, it is as easy as parsing Json File. this [tuto](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization) will help you to figure out. 
However, bescause it is is a nested xml, you will need some nested POJOs to achieve parsing.